# Find the maximum of $|cosz|$ on the square $Re(z),Im(z)\in [0,2\pi]$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the maximum of $|cosz|$ on the square $Re(z),Im(z)\in [0,2\pi]$.

The answer in the textbook of Basic Complex Analysis by Marsden is the maximum is achieved when $z=2\pi i, \pi + 2\pi i, 2\pi + 2\pi i$. I am not sure how this was achieved though? I did not study any maximum or minimum problems yet in complex analysis. Do I have to take any derivatives?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Hint: Apply maximum modulus theorem. Check the values of $|1/2(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})|$ on the boundary of the square.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather elementary proof. Since
$$ \cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2},$$ 
if $z = a + bi$ then 
$$ \cos(z) = \frac{e^{-b}e^{ai} + e^be^{-ai}}{2}.$$
To maximise $\lvert\cos(z)\rvert$ is to maximise $\lvert 2\cos(z) \rvert^2$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
|e^{-b}e^{ai} + e^be^{-ai}|^2 &= |e^{-b}(\cos(a) + i\sin(a)) + e^b(\cos(a) - i\sin(a))|^2 \\
&=\cos^2(a)(e^{-b} + e^b)^2 + \sin^2(a)(e^{-b} - e^b)^2 \\
&= e^b + e^{-b} + 2(\cos^2(a) - \sin^2(a)). \\ 
\end{align*}
You can then maximise over $a$ and $b$ independently.