# Specific doubts about complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

On the one hand, in the problem of the next link,

[Proof that $e^{i\bar{z}}=\overline{e^{iz}}$ if and only if $z=k\pi\in Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646845/proof-that-ei-barz-overlineeiz-if-and-only-if-z-k-pi-in-z)

we are having that

$$\overline{e^{iz}} = e^{i\bar{z}} \Longleftrightarrow (\cos(a)-i\sin(a)) e^{-b} = (\cos(a)+i\sin(a)) e^{b} \Longleftrightarrow e^{-b} = e^b ~\&~ -\sin(a) = \sin(a), \quad (*)$$

Since $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $b$ is forced to be $0$ and $a = k\pi$, forall $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But the thing is, that we can use $z = k_1\pi + k_2\pi i$, forall $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the equation in $(*)$ with this "more general solution" stills working. In this case, we are taking $b = k_2\pi i$ strictly an imaginary number.

On the other hand, in the problem of the next link,

[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515468/find-the-maximum-of-\cosz-on-the-square-rez-imz-in-0-2-pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515468/find-the-maximum-of-%5Ccosz-on-the-square-rez-imz-in-0-2-pi)

we are requested to look for the maxima of the function $|\cos(z)|$. So we need to use the next function:

$$\nabla|2\phi(a, b)|^2 = \Big(-8 \cos(a) \sin(a), 2e^{2b} -2 e^{-2b}\Big)$$

In this case, we previously observed that

$$\phi(a, b) = \Big(\frac{(e^{-b}+e^{b})\cos(a)}{2},\frac{(e^{-b}-e^{b})\sin(a)}{2}\Big), \quad a, b \in \mathbb{R}$$

repre\sints the same function as $\cos(z)$, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus, we need values $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\nabla|2\phi(a, b)|^2 = (0,0)$. So $b = 0$ and $a = k_1 \pi$ or $a = k_1 \pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$, forall $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But we cannot find the maxima with the values $(a, 0)$ for $a = k_1 \pi$ or $a = k_1 \pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$. To find the maxima values we are required to take $b \in \mathbb{C}$ as $b = k_2 \pi i$ or $b = k_2 \pi i - \frac{\pi}{2} i$, forall $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I cannot find the problem of my interpretation on why in the first case we can use $b$ as an imaginary number and in the second case we need $b$ strictly an imaginary number, when in both cases we supposed that $b$ was a real.

Comment: When we write $z = a + bi$ to deduce (*), we're assuming $a$ and $b$ are _real_. The fact that $b = 0$ implies $k_{2} = 0$. <> Haven't looked at the second question.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang But if $k_2 \neq 0$, $b \not\in \mathbb{R}$, but in $\mathbb{C}$. I mean, my semantic interpretation is missing something. The second case leads to the inverse problem, that is $b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Maybe the issue is, if $a$, $b$, $a'$, and $b'$ are _real_, then $a+bi=a'+b'i$ if and only if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$. If instead $a$, $b$, $a'$, $b'$ are complex, however, the same conclusion does not follow. (For example, take $a = i$, $b = 0$, $a' = 0$, $b' = 1$.)

Comment: Thanks! Confusions solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\ \big|\phi(a,b)\big|^2\ $ is strictly increasing in $\ b\ $ for $\ b\in[0,2\pi]\ ,$ so its maxima *don't* occur at points where $\ \frac{\partial\big|\phi(a,b)\big|^2}{\partial b}=0\ $, but at points where $\ b=2\pi\ $, which is not an imaginary number. Remember that $\ z=a+ib\ $, so for the three maxima given in the text book cited at the link you've given, you have
\begin{align}
z=2\pi i,&a=0,b=2\pi\\
z=\pi+2\pi i,&a=\pi, b=2\pi\\
z=2\pi+2\pi i,&a=2\pi, b=2\pi\ .
\end{align}
In no case is $\ b\ $ imaginary.

Comment: Now I think I understood. By $\phi(a, b)^2$ you mean $$\phi(a, b)^2 = \Big(\Big(\frac{(e^{-b}+e^{b})\cos(a)}{2}\Big)^2 - \Big(\frac{(e^{-b}-e^{b})\sin(a)}{2}\Big)^2, \frac{(e^{-b}+e^{b})^2\cos(a)\sin(a)}{2}\Big)$$ ?

Comment: My apologies. I intended $\ \phi\ $ to be mean the  same thing as in your post, but I forgot to put the absolute value signs around it to get the function you're trying to maximise.  I've now added them.

Comment: I got it! Indeed, Since there is no $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\partial |\phi|^2}{\partial b} = 0$, one must observe that it is strictly increasing! Thanks!